# Is there an equivalent to SuppressWarnings in Scala?

Tags: scala, suppress-warnings

I was wondering if scala had an equivalent to java's [@SuppressWarnings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) that can be applied to a function or whatever to ignore any deprecation warnings[1] that function emits?

1: Relevant warning in my case is: `method stop in class Thread is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.` I am aware of the problems with stop however there are still some cases where due to legacy code we have to use it.

Comment: Good question! In my case, I compile with -Xmigration because it is useful when testing code found on Internet, and I get "

Answer (score 30, accepted):

No, and an enhancement request [1] for such a feature was closed as `wontfix`.

I agree it would be useful. I expect that the Scala core team aren't against the idea, but they have finite resources and many higher priorities.

*update*: this feature was eventually implemented in scala 2.13.2 release on 2020-04-22, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528630/572635)

[1] https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1781

Comment: That request was for an `@unchecked` annotation.  The OP is concerned with deprecation warnings rather than unsafe cast warnings.

Comment: You're right. A comment on the ticket did suggest @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/1781#comment:3

Comment: A pity. Not being able to distinguish between good and bad warnings makes them pretty much useless in a big project's build report.

Comment: Ahem. There is no such thing as a "good" warning. A warning is a problem that doesn't kill you right now, but might kill you tomorrow. Just becasue Java is such a broken language, we got the very bad habit to ignore warnings.

Comment: @Ichthyo What you say is nice in theory, but not true in practice.

Warnings are here to give mere hints, and they are often *false positives*, even in Scala (otherwise they would be errors!).


In case of a false positive, it would be better to add a comment as to why it is so, and disable it. Otherwise it pollutes the project report and make less visible the *genuine warnings* that may reveal *a real threat* to the safety of the program!

Comment: @Ichthyo I'm sorry if I offended you; wasn't my intention. I'm not sure what you mean by "obviously lacking the experience of a huge and long standing code base drowned in warnings". I did work on such projects (granted, not in Scala; it was C++). Removing those warnings (whether caused by real problems or not) was indeed a priority. I guess every project and associated policy is different anyway. My point was that in some contexts, it can be justified to hide particular warnings at particular place, to keep everything else simple and coherent

Comment: Though closed, it eventually got implemented, in time for Scala 2.13.2.

Comment: I amended the answer for scala 2.13.2 since it's the first google result and accepted answer @DanielC.Sobral

Answer (score 27):

**EDIT**: You should use [@nowarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528630/931323)

---

There is a simple compiler plugin for this: [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) (a bit shameless plug)

Comment: Why do you think that it's shameless?

Comment: @Simon that's an expression, no need to take it literally :)

Comment: @Simon "shameless plug", because he's the author of the plugin.

Answer (score 18):

Scala 2.13.2 provides [`@nowarn`](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/configurable-warnings-warning-suppression/4096?u=mario-galic) annotation developed on the basis of ghik's `silencer`, for example

```
import scala.annotation.nowarn
def t = { 0: @nowarn; 1 }
```

raises no warnings, whilst

```
def t = { 0; 1 }
```

gives

```
warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; multiline expressions might require enclosing parentheses
  def t = { 0; 1 }
            ^
```

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Seems it was [renamed](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/8373#issuecomment-595211382) from `silent` to `nowarn` [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/0dce86940af26ca838df5aa7cf8b9490cacc5947).

Comment: Full usage it available in `scalac -Wconf:help`

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to suppress all warnings in sbt:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import KeyRanks.DTask
import xsbti.{Reporter, Problem, Position, Severity}

private lazy val compilerReporter = TaskKey[xsbti.Reporter](
  "compilerReporter",
  "Experimental hook to listen (or send) compilation failure messages.",
  DTask
)

val ignoreWarnings = Seq(
  compilerReporter in (Compile, compile) :=
    new xsbti.Reporter {
      private val buffer = collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.empty[Problem]
      def reset(): Unit = buffer.clear()
      def hasErrors: Boolean = buffer.exists(_.severity == Severity.Error)
      def hasWarnings: Boolean = buffer.exists(_.severity == Severity.Warn)
      def printSummary(): Unit = {

        print("\033c")
        if (problems.nonEmpty) {
          problems.foreach{ p =>
            println("=====================================================")
            println(p.position)
            println(p.message)
            println()
            println()
          }
        }
      }
      def problems: Array[Problem] = buffer.toArray

      def log(problem: Problem): Unit = {
        if (problem.severity == Severity.Error) {
          buffer.append(problem)
        }
      }
      def log(pos: Position, msg: String, sev: Severity): Unit = {
        log(new Problem {
          def category: String = "foo"
          def severity: Severity = sev
          def message: String = msg
          def position: Position = pos
        })
      }
      def comment(pos: xsbti.Position, msg: String): Unit = ()
    }
)
```