# Scala: How to suppress unchecked warnings / do pattern matching of maps correctly?

Tags: scala

In a test call a third-party function which returns an `Option[Any]`. I know if this function returns a `Map`, it is a `Map[String, Any]`. In this case, I want to check for individual map elements.

```
theFunction(...) match {
  case Some(m: Map[String, Any]) =>
    m("some key") match {
      case some_condition => ... (my check)
    }
  case _ => fail("Invalid type")
}
```

But the compiler warns that `case Some(m: Map[String, Any])` is unchecked. When I use `Map[_,_]` instead, the compiler bails out at the point where I check `m("some key")`.

How do I suppress this warning, or better: how do I do this check correctly? The only approach I can think of is something like

```
theFunction(...) match {
  case Some(m: Map[_,_]) =>
    val m1: Map[String, Any] = m.toSeq.map(t => t._1.asInstanceOf[String] -> t._2).toMap
    m1("some key") match {
      case some_condition => ... (my check)
    }
}
```

but in my eyes, this looks ugly and introduces unnecessary converting of the map to a Seq and vice-versa.

Comment: I accepted the second answer, and I use my complicated way as it is used in a test, and there it is good to have more detailed error information if anything should not be as expected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is currently no way to suppress these warnings in Scala.  There's some interesting discussion about the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506370/is-there-an-equivalent-to-suppresswarnings-in-scala).  You can ignore the warning, or use `asInstanceOf`:

```
m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]("some key") match { ... }
```

These types of runtime operations are error prone, and usually point to a poor type system.  There are very few situations in which a method should return `Option[Any]`.  Almost any use of `Any` as a return type is a red flag in Scala.

Comment: There is a way to suppress these warnings, see the other answers.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the [unchecked](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.unchecked) annotation to suppress compiler warnings like these (for non-exhaustive matches and fruitless matches due to type erasure).

From the scaladoc:

> An annotation to designate that the annotated entity should not be considered for additional compiler checks. Specific applications include annotating the subject of a match expression to suppress exhaustiveness warnings, and annotating a type argument in a match case to suppress unchecked warnings.
>
> Such suppression should be used with caution, without which one may encounter scala.MatchError or java.lang.ClassCastException at runtime. In most cases one can and should address the warning instead of suppressing it.

Example:

```
val m: Any = Some(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "b"))
m match {
    case Some(m: Map[String, Any]) => println("map")
    case None => println("None")
}

<console>:30: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] (the underlying of Map[String,Any]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
                  case Some(m: Map[String, Any]) => println("map")
```

We can add the `@unchecked` annotation to `Map[String, Any]` within the match:

```
m match {
    case Some(m: Map[String, Any] @unchecked) => println("I'm a map!")
    case None => println("None")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

I'm a map!
```

No more warning. But this is obviously no more safe than allowing the warning, and could lead to some surprising match errors or `ClassCastException`s.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not sure, if it is related to question, but you can wherever you want add type annotations.

For example, I have

```
type H = List[Int]
def sum_dummy(h: H): Int = {
   if (isEmpty(h)) throw new NoSuchElementException()
   else (h:H @unchecked) match {
      case x::list => x + func(list)
   }
}
```

you can rewrite example with `case Nil`usage for full idiomatic scala, but I wrote it for type annotation example.