# Where to put the `@unchecked` to suppress "pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked"?

Tags: scala, annotations, warnings, suppress-warnings, unchecked

When I run the following code snippet with `scala`

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

def foo(a: Option[Any]): Option[Any] = {
  a.filter {
    case x: { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
  }
}

object Bar {
  def bar: Boolean = true
}

println(foo(Some(Bar)))
```

I get a warning

> warning: a pattern match on a refinement type is unchecked

I've tried the following:

```
@unchecked case x: { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
case (@unchecked x): { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
case (x @unchecked): { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
case x: @unchecked { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
case x: { def bar: Boolean } @unchecked => x.bar
case (x: { def bar: Boolean } @unchecked) => x.bar
case x: ({ def bar: Boolean } @unchecked) => x.bar
case x: { def bar: Boolean } => (x @unchecked).bar
case x: { def bar: Boolean } => (x: { def bar: Boolean } @unchecked).bar
```

None of those work. This also doesn't work:

```
  a.filter { any => (any: @unchecked) match {
    case x: { def bar: Boolean } => x.bar
  }}
```

How do I suppress this warning?

---

**Somewhat related links**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29987749/2707792) seems to use the `@unchecked` successfully inside `Some(...)`, but I don't see how to use it with `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An additional pair of round parentheses around the `{ def ... }` is required:

```
case x: ({ def bar: Boolean }) @unchecked => x.bar
```

With the additional parentheses, it compiles just fine, without any warnings.

---

This seems to be similar to the syntax for the "classical type-lambdas", where

```
({ type Lam[X] = Foo[X] })#Lam
```

worked, whereas

```
{ type Lam[X] = Foo[X] }#Lam
```

didn't.