# Suppress unused warnings in a particular scope

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, implicit, suppress-warnings

In Scala (2.12) when writing a trait I have added a default implementation that can be overridden by some subclasses. Since throughout my entire implementation the `state` is required almost everywhere it's *implicit* such that I don't have to pass it every time it's required.

Considering the following code snippet, the compiler does complain that the implicit parameter `state` of `SomeTrait.defaultMethod` remains unused and throws an error. Is there any option to suppress this kind of error in that particular scope? I definitely want to keep the unused errors globally.

```scala
trait SomeTrait {

  def defaultMethod(implicit state: State) : Unit = {
     // default implemenation does nothing
  }
}

class Subclass extends SomeTrait{

 override def deafultMethod(implicit state: State) : Unit = {
    state.addInformation()
 }
}
```

Also, I would like to keep the state implicit. In theory, it's possible to add a fake usage to the method but that's not a clean solution.

Comment: If the default implementation does nothing and it is intended to always be overriden, why not leave it abstract? - If you are in `2.13` you can use the **@Unused** _annotation_., you can `val _ = state` in the implementation, or you can add this helper: `def void(args: Any*): Unit = ((), args)._1` which you can use to discard any unused like `void(foo, bar)` - Finally, an implicit global mutable state sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Mmh thanks, that might help. No worries, the state here is not global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0) introduced `@unused` annotation

> This annotation is useful for suppressing warnings under `-Xlint`.
>   ([#7623](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7623))

Here are few [examples](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/blob/2.13.x/test/files/neg/t10790.scala)

```
// scalac: -Xfatal-warnings -Ywarn-unused

import annotation.unused

class X {
  def f(@unused x: Int) = 42       // no warn

  def control(x: Int) = 42         // warn to verify control

  private class C                  // warn
  @unused private class D          // no warn

  private val Some(y) = Option(42) // warn
  @unused private val Some(z) = Option(42) // no warn

  @unused("not updated") private var i = 42       // no warn
  def g = i

  @unused("not read") private var j = 42       // no warn
  def update() = j = 17
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use Scala 2.13.

Comment: @M.Reif Note silencer will be incorporated into Scala 2.13.2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528630/5205022