# NoWarn Is Not A Valid Choice for -Wunused Compiler Error

Tags: scala, sbt

I added `sbt-toplecat` to my repo and I fixed most of the errors with my code but there is one issue I'm not sure how to fix:

```scala
'nowarn' is not a valid choice for '-Wunused'
```

I am running Scala 2.13. How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`nowarn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60528630/5205022) is available from Scala 2.13.2. I am guessing you updated to `sbt-tpolecat` 0.1.12, which added this option in [Add -Wunused:nowarn to 2.13 builds. #21](https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat/pull/21)

```
addSbtPlugin("io.github.davidgregory084" % "sbt-tpolecat" % "0.1.12")
```

however kept your Scala version at 2.13.1 or 2.13.0

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
```

To fix the issue try updating Scala version to 2.13.2

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.2"
```