# How can I tell scalac to suppress warnings is macro-generated code?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scalac, scala-2.13

I'm currently using a macro (ZIO's `@mockable`) whose generated code is causing a compilation error that is causing my build to fail:

```
[error] /home/me/xxx/backend/<macro>:5:204: parameter value rts in anonymous function is never used
[error]   val compose: _root_.zio.URLayer[_root_.zio.Has[_root_.zio.test.mock.Proxy], zio.Has[my.package.database.firestore.Firestore.Service]] = _root_.zio.ZLayer.fromServiceM(((proxy) => withRuntime.map(((rts) => {
[error]                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
[error] one error found
```

How can I suppress this warning? I've tried adding `"-Wconf:src=.*<macro>:silent"` (with and without escaping `<` and `>`) but with no luck.

Comment: Does `-Ywarn-macros:before` works for you?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I need to have `"-Wmacros:after"` set because of other macros :/

Comment: Can you use `@nowarn`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506370/is-there-an-equivalent-to-suppresswarnings-in-scala

Comment: Open a PR for the same issue than you: https://github.com/zio/zio/pull/6472